# Apache2 subdomain not found after addition

Tags: debian, virtualhost, domain, apache2, subdomain

Here is a situation

I have `example.com` domain pointed to my server where **Apache2** runs.
Currently I have two confs (one for HTTP and one for HTTPS) that accepts example.com requests and shows page thats stored in folder `/var/ww/html/example`

**HTTP conf** (`example.com.conf`)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
ErrorLog logs/example.com-error_log
CustomLog logs/example.com-access_log common
Redirect permanent / https://example.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

*HTTPS conf is basic conf generated by `certbot` with no changes*

But what I want to achieve now is to have subdomain `demo.example.com` which simply points to root html folder `/var/www/html/` (so if I type `demo.example.com/some-folder` is shows content of this folder)

So I´ve tried this

**HTTP conf** (`exampledemo.com.conf`)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName demo.example.com
ServerAlias www.demo.example.com
ErrorLog logs/demo.example.com-error_log
CustomLog logs/demo.example.com-access_log common
Redirect permanent / https://demo.example.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =demo.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.demo.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

*HTTPS conf is basic conf generated by `certbot` with no changes*

But when I added site and restarted apache, **I am getting not found page** that I have on my server as fallback so this configuration probably does not match my conf

**HTTP conf** (`000-default.conf`)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/not-found
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: first thing you need to make sure your configfile loaded in Apache by run `apache2ctl -S` if the conf not loaded its mean you place the config file inside wrong apache dir.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your configuration is conflicting with the default configuration `000-default.conf` which is serving the `"not found"` page.

1. Disable the default configuration:

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

2. Check the DNS settings:

```
nslookup demo.example.com
```

3. Check the Apache configuration:

Make sure that your new configuration file `exampledemo.com.conf` is in the correct directory `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` and that it has the correct permissions.

You can also check the Apache error log for any errors related to the configuration. The error log is usually located at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Then restart Apache:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```